# Removing event listeners for Dojo dGrids

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I"m creating dGrids programmatically and adding listeners for event such as the ".dgrid-row:click", mouseUtil.enterRow, and mouseUtil.leaveRow. If I'm doing this for a single grid, it would be easy to do something like this to create the listener and remove it when I'm finished with the grid.

```
var clickEvent = dataGrid.on(".dgrid-row:click", gridSelect);
//code
clickEvent.remove();
```

However, I'm creating several dGrids in a loop.

```
for (result in results) {
    var dataGrid = new (declare([Grid, Selection, DijitRegistry, ColumnHider]))({
        id: "dgrid_" + result.name,
        bufferRows: Infinity,
        columns: result.columns,
        selectionMode: "single",
        "class": "resultsGrid"
    });

    dataGrid.on(".dgrid-row:click", gridSelect);
    dataGrid.on(mouseUtil.enterRow, gridEnter);
    dataGrid.on(mouseUtil.enterRow, gridEnter);

    dataGrid.renderArray(result.data);
}
```

The grids are being added to a TabContainer. What is the best way to remove all the listeners when I get rid of the TabContainer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the grid's own `on` method, it will automatically remove these listeners when the grid's `destroy` method is called (particularly in old IE; newer browsers should be able to properly GC by themselves).

Since you're mixing in `DijitRegistry`, your `TabContainer` should automatically destroy the grids when respective tabs are closed or the container itself is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks. I was suspecting that was the case, but I wanted to be sure about it.